# xpages Mobile Date Picker

Tags: mobile, datepicker, xpages

Perhaps I am missing something obvious, but when I utilize the dojo date picker with a mobile application, the control renders incorrectly, is there a different date picker control for the mobile apps or something obvious I am overlooking?

A little more information, the date picker controls work fine, until I name the XPage so that it matches the xsp.theme.mobile.pagePrefix pattern then it changes to 2 boxes, a bullet icon and a grayed out icon?  Other strange activity happens when you pop the calendar like being able to see a list of all the months, a calendar and 3 years choices, but everything is blown apart and not formated properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Declan that HTML5 would be the solution for IOS5, and I think it's the trend in future browser development.

However, in case your mobile Web app needs to support both iPhone, iPad and Android now, you may have to consider an alternative solution.

For example, you can try using mobiscroll, which is a jQuery plugin:
http://code.google.com/p/mobiscroll/

You will have to include mobiscroll-1.6.min.css, mobiscroll-1.6.min.js and jquery-1.7.2.min.js to your Xpage.

Note that the "x$ jQuery selector for XPages" XSnippet may be useful to you too:
http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=x-jquery-selector-for-xpages

Hope it helps.

Comment: This comment rocks, I rebuilt the entire date selector using this method and it works perfect, I have just come to accept if I want a date picker with a pop up calendar to work everywhere mobile give up and use jquery mobile date datebox.  Its a bit of work and effort, but the results are consistent.  My solution before just didn't cut it as I crossed different android software revisions, etc.

Answer (score 5):

When using the xsp.theme.mobile.pagePrefix parameter a different theme file is used for the page depending on the mobile device being used. This theme file does not load in the dojo tundra css files and doesn't load in the oneUI css files that are necessary for the dojo date picker control to work.

You could use the native date picker on the mobile device, just use a normal edit control and then in the properties set the type to 'datetime'. This will add the required html5 complient input type to the tag when it is rendered by the mobile web browser and then device will then show the native picker.

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding your suggestion correctly, but if I add the following to my xpage:
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" type="datetime"></xp:inputText>
I get the same a generic text box, with no calendar controls.

Comment: You didn't specify which mobile device your using. This is an iOS feature that isn't supporting in Android 4.0 YET

Answer (score 1):

Declan has the right response, just note the HTML 5 doesn't work in Android devices, just the iPhone (maybe some Blackberrys...)

Howard

Answer (score 0):

@Howard, A dojo date picker nor native date picker works on Ipad when used with mobile extensions provided by Lotus. The date picker format is lost for ever. However both contols works fine on ipad when not used along with mobile extensions.